# Connect to specific port on ip

Tags: iphone, ios, connection, port

Maybe pretty basic question, but I can't find a basic example or explanation.

I want to make a connection to 192.168.0.10 with port nr 35000
When I have a connection, I want to post AT commands and/or create a socket stream.
How do I code this in iOS? I have seen an example with NSPort, but I can't find it anymore :(

Objective is to create a connection and keep it open through several views. And also post different commands to retreive data and display it on the different views.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Kind regards,
Robert

Comment: Just pass the port number as part of the URL - `192.168.0.10:35000`.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html